# linking error in vc ++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i have Point3D class in my project.
to create an object of Point3D i have added a cpp file & a header file as follows:
CreatePoint.h

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma once
#include "Point3D.h"

//*******************************************************************
int counter = 0;
int size = 50;
Point3D **point;

//*******************************************************************
void create_array(int);//this will be called in main & pass 50//this is the method to             create an array of pointers to Point3D

//*******************************************************************
void resize();//this increases the size of array if size - 5 elements are filled &     increases size by 25

//*******************************************************************
Point3D *get_point(int);//this returns the pointer according to the index

//*******************************************************************
int get_index(Point3D *);//this returns the index of a point

//*******************************************************************
void move_point(int, int);//this interchanges the memory locations of 2 points

//*******************************************************************
void del_point(Point3D *);//this makes NULL value to the passed point

//*******************************************************************
void destruct_point();//this is called when the program ends by me
```

& the cpp file is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CreatePoint.h"

//*******************************************************************
void create_array(int s)
{
point = new Point3D *[s];
for (int i = 0; i<s; i++)
{
    point[i] = NULL;
}
}

//*******************************************************************
void resize()
{
Point3D **copy = new Point3D *[size];
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    copy[i] = point[i];
}

delete [] point;

size += 25;
create_array(size);

for(int i = 0; i<(size - 25); i++)
{
    point[i] = copy[i];
}

delete [] copy;
}

//*******************************************************************
Point3D *get_point(int i)
{
if((size - counter) == 5)
    resize();
return point[i];
}

//*******************************************************************
int get_index(Point3D *p)
{
for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    if(point[i] == p)
        return i;
}
return -1;
}

//*******************************************************************
void move_point(int a, int b)
{
Point3D *apt = get_point(a);
Point3D *bpt = get_point(b);

Point3D *t = new Point3D;
t = apt;
apt = bpt;
bpt = t;

delete t;
}

//*******************************************************************
void del_point(Point3D *p)
{
int d = get_index(p);
move_point(d, counter - 1);
point[counter - 1] = NULL;
}

//*******************************************************************
void destruct_point()
{
delete [] point;
point = NULL;
}
```

i am getting some linking errors:

```
stdafx.obj : error LNK2005: "class Point3D * * point" (?point@@3PAPAVPoint3D@@A)     already defined in CreatePoint.obj
1>stdafx.obj : error LNK2005: "int counter" (?counter@@3HA) already defined in     CreatePoint.obj
1>stdafx.obj : error LNK2005: "int size" (?size@@3HA) already defined in CreatePoint.obj
1>C:\Documents and Settings\SUMIT & AMIT\my documents\visual studio     2010\Projects\Maths\Debug\Maths.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined     symbols found
```

can anybody please help me!!!
also, any suggestions on the code will be appreciated :)
THANKS A LOT FOR READING MY POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In header file use `extern` when *declaring* the variables, as:

```
//CreatePoint.h
extern int counter;       //it is only a declaration
extern int size;          //it is only a declaration
extern Point3D **point;   //it is only a declaration
```

And in the source file, *define* and initialize them as:

```
//CreatePoint.cpp

#include "CreatePoint.h"

int counter = 0;   //it is the definition
int size = 50;     //it is the definition
Point3D **point;   //it is the definition
```

You get multiple definitions error, because you include `CreatePoint.h` more than one `.cpp` file which defines the same variables more than once. Using `extern` in header file, avoids this, because it doesn't *define* them, it simply *declares* them, while the actual *definition* goes in the `.cpp` file.

The keyword `extern` tells the compiler to look for the *definition* elsewhere. The `extern` statements in the header are only *declaration* of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring & defining these variables directly in a header file.  Every CPP file that includes this H file will get it's own definition of it, which is in violation of the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

You need to change your design so that there is only one definition.  You could make them `extern` in the H file:

### CreatePoint.H

```
extern int counter;
extern int size;
extern Point3D **point;
```

...and then define them in the CPP file:

### CreatePoint.CPP

```
int counter = 0;
int size = 50;
Point3D** point = 0;
```

Global variables are generally bad, however.  You should redesign your code so as to not use them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare variables as `extern` in the header because they are outside a function block. If they were declared inside a function, they would be considered `automatic`